# Public database with celebrity names?

Tags: wikidata, large-datasets

Essentially I have a list of customer names (first, last), and we want to know whether or not any of these have celebrity status, so looking to cross-reference my list with an external database.

Again, I only need their first + last name, and to know whether or not they are a public figure (eg. do they have a Wikipedia entry about them?), with no need for other personal information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A problem with that is that incredibly many unknown people have the exact same names than famous people - dead or alive. So just a name is not a guarantee that someone is famous. Consider that you may annoy people who did not ask for anything, or that you may make wrong claims about who you clients are -and lose customers over it. 

If you're absolutely certain it won't be the case (for some reason that you didn't mention in your post), here is some code you can adapt to check if names in your database have some matching article on wikipedia: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search#Python